# Silverlight resizable container by mouse

Tags: silverlight, controls

Just checking to see if a free control with the following feature is available before I go build one.

I'm looking for a container that contains grips in which I can drag and re-size, much like a window.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a FloatableWindow control available on CodePlex, which is basically the Silverlight ChildWindow refactored to allow for non-modal use. Supports both dragging and resizing.

http://floatablewindow.codeplex.com/

Comment: thx, i actually started rewriting that control already for my own use.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but take a look at Blacklight contols.

Interactive Controls -> Drag Drop Panel

http://mightymeaty.members.winisp.net/blacklight.silverlight/